# How to make my own masked input definitions

Tags: javascript, plugins, jquery-plugins, maskedinput

I am using the masked input plugin for phone number formatting, http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

The standard definitions are

```
        definitions: {
        "9": "[0-9]",
        a: "[A-Za-z]",
        "*": "[A-Za-z0-9]"
        },
```

Currently if I apply the mask (999) 999-9999, I can enter any 0-9 character.

How can I create my own or modify a definition so that it could also accept '*' or '/' characters?

Comment: They look like standard regex. Have you tried `[0-9*/]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `[0-9]` to `[0-9*/]` to accept both numbers and `*` or `/`.

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution, didn't realize it was just a standard regex.